# View - Merge Rows Based on Value of Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I'm creating a View for something required.
It shows all open orders within a specific date range, however each individual item is showing instead of totalling the order.

Below is how it shows for the moment

[image: Current]

However, I need the Value and Margin to combine into two totals based on the OrderNo

Hope this is doable, I've hit a wall

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. A tinted image of partial results isn't much to go on without DDL, the input data and the query.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like aggregation.  I can only guess at what values define each row, but a reasonable guess is:

```
select custcode, ordno, type, date, sum(value) as value, sum(margin) as margin
from t
group by custcode, ordno, type, date;
```

Note that if you have a view you are developing for this purpose, you can probably put this logic in the view.  If you cannot adapt this code to your view, ask a *new* question, provide the view definition (perhaps simplified) as well as sample data and desired results *as text tables*.